# Chern-Simons Realization of Dijkgraaf-Witten Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

There is a realization of $Z_N$ Chern-Simons theory (Dijkgraaf-Witten theory) using an instance of $U(1) \times U(1)$ Chern-Simons theory. As explained on page 38 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.05915 , this is realized via the Lagrangian

$$
\frac{k}{4 \pi} \widehat{a} d \widehat{a}+\frac{N}{2 \pi} \widehat{a} d \widehat{b}
$$
They claim that integrating out the gauge field $\widehat{b}$ constrains $\widehat{a}$ to be a $\mathbb{Z}_{N}$ gauge field $\oint \widehat{a} \in \frac{2 \pi}{N} \mathbb{Z}$.

Why is this so? It seems to me that integrating out $\widehat{b}$ gives $d\widehat{a}=0$ via integration by parts.

Comment: it gives not $d\hat a=0$, but $Nd\hat a=0$. Thus, $\hat a$ is a $Z_N$ gauge field. $Nd\hat a=0$ is basically what it means to be a $Z_N$ gauge field. The integrating out of $\hat b$ locally sets $\hat a=0$, but not globally (you still have holonomies).

Comment: Why is $N d \widehat{a}=0$ not the same as $d \widehat{a}=0$, given that right hand side of both equations is zero? I can't see how holonomies would make a distinction between these two equations.

Comment: How do you define a $Z_N$ gauge theory? Usually, you have line operators that satisfy $U^N=1$. In terms of a $U(1)$ gauge field, if you write $U=e^{i\oint a}$, the condition becomes $N\oint a=0$, i.e., $Nda=0$. You can introduce patches and then $a$ is locally constant, etc. This can be done if you don't like this heuristic argument. Are you following a specific reference where $Z_N$ gauge theories are defined? What is the definition?